# Backbone model.destroy with MongoDB persistence

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to Backbone and to MongoDB. I'm running into problems destroying models (that are backed by MongoDB). I **believe** it has something to do with the fact that a MongoDB "document" uses the abnormal `_id` attribute and is not wired up with Backbone by default. I've tried setting `idAttribute: '_id'` which does not seem to solve the issue.

**A sample Mongo document looks like:**

```
{
  _id: Object
    $oid: "527303e82f3504ba5bf4b21f"
  __proto__: Object
  feeling: "ok"
  location: "california"
  name: "Kevin"
}
```

**models.coffee**

```
class Models.Campaign extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: "http://localhost:4567/api/campaigns"
  # setting idAttribute: '_id' causes issues rendering the Backbone collection
```

**controller.coffee**

```
...
model.destroy() #=> only removes the item from the dom but does not make a DELETE request
```

Am I able to pass in an `id` to the destroy() function?

Does anyone have advise in how to properly wire up Backbone with MongoDB without having to monkeypatch a ton of built-in Backbone functions?

Comment: Does `urlRoot: '/api/campaigns'` work? Combined with `idAttribute: '_id'` of course.

Comment: not exactly... setting `idAttribute: 'id'` disrupts the loading of the Backbone collection but does attempt to make an AJAX delete request with the wrong parameter (i really need `_id.$oid` as shown above)

Comment: Does the JSON the comes from the server look like that `{_id: ..., $oid: ... }`? Presumably the server wants to see `DESTROY /api/campaigns/527303e82f3504ba5bf4b21f` to kill the (server-side) model, right?

Comment: exactly right, i can't seem to pass in that id (`527303e82f3504ba5bf4b21f`) to Backbone's destroy() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have an easier time if you add a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to your model to sort out the confusing data you're getting from the server. You don't need or care about `_id`, you do care about `$oid`, and Backbone would prefer to work with an `id` property; you can sort out all three with a simple `parse` in your model like this:

```
parse: function(response) {
    var parsed = _(response).pick(
        'feeling',
        'location',
        'name'
    );
    parsed.id = response.$oid;
    return parsed;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pn773/

You'd probably be fine if your `parse` modified `response` rather than making a semi-copy using [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) and modifying that copy, however, `parse` doesn't technically own `response` so it would be rude to change it and there could be surprising side effects. Good habits, etc.

Then when Backbone tries to convert the server's data to a model, it will end up working with:

```
{
  id: "527303e82f3504ba5bf4b21f",
  feeling: "ok",
  location: "california",
  name: "Kevin"
}
```

and everyone should be happy:

1. Backbone won't see the irrelevant `_id`.
2. Backbone won't see `$oid` and you won't need to set `idAttribute` to anything special.
3. Backbone will see an `id` like it expects and all the standard machinery will use the BSON ObjectId as the model's unique identifier.

The simple method should get you your `DELETE /api/campaigns/527303e82f3504ba5bf4b21f` request when you `model.destroy()`.

Comment: thanks for the clear detailed answer. `parse()` looks like the way to go...i was trying to avoid overwriting Backbone functions, but in this case, I do think its justified in order to sanitize the object. thanks @mu

Comment: `parse` exists for a reason, there's no reason to avoid implementing your own `parse` when you need to standardize incoming data.

Comment: implementing now...will post as answer as soon as i get it rolling..thanks again for the suggestion

Comment: works well, i used the inverse of `_.pick` and opted for `_.omit` but everything else the same. thanks again